# Laplacian kernels of higher order in image processing

Tags: image-processing, kernel, laplacian

In literature on digital image processing you find examples of Laplace kernels of relatively low orders, typically, 3 or 5. I wonder, is there any general way to build Laplace kernels or arbitrary order? Links or/and references would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "order"? The approximation order of the finite differences?

Comment: Or do you mean the size of the kernel? If so, look for Laplace of Gaussian.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes, this is what I mean

Comment: @Cris Luengo I imagine that the size of the kernel and the approximation order are the same number. Anyway, it is not LoG what I mean, but rather the Laplace kernel pure.

Answer (score 2):

The [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) is defined as the sum of the second derivatives along each of the axes of the image. (That is, it is the trace of the Hessian matrix):

- Δ *I* = ( ∂<sup>2</sup>/∂*x*<sup>2</sup> + ∂<sup>2</sup>/∂*y*<sup>2</sup> ) *I*

There are two common ways to discretize this:

1. Use finite differences. The derivative operator is the convolution by `[1,-1]` or `[0.5,0,-0.5]`, the second derivative operator applying the `[1,-1]` convolution twice, leading to a convolution with `[1,-2,1]`.
2. Convolve with the derivative of a regularization kernel. The optimal regularization kernel is the Gaussian, leading to a Laplace of Gaussian operator. The result is the **exact** Laplace of the image smoothed by the Gaussian kernel.

---

An alternative is to replace the regularization kernel with an interpolating kernel. A former colleague of mine published a paper on this method:

> A. Hast, "Simple filter design for first and second order derivatives by a double filtering approach", [Pattern Recognition Letters 42(1):65-71, 2014](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865514000282).

He used a "double filter", but with linear filters that can always be simplified to a single convolution.

The idea is simply that, take an interpolating kernel, and compute its derivative at integer locations. The interpolating kernel is always 1 at the origin, and 0 at other integer locations, but it waves through these "knot points", meaning that its derivative is not zero at these integer locations.

In the extreme case, take the ideal interpolator, the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function):

- sinc(*x*) = sin(π*x*) / π*x*

Its [second derivative is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2%20sinc(pi%20x)):

- d<sup>2</sup>/d*x*<sup>2</sup>(sinc(π*x*)) = [ (2 - π<sup>2</sup>*x*<sup>2</sup>) sin(π*x*) - 2π*x* cos(π*x*) ] / (π*x*<sup>3</sup>)

Which sampled at 11 integer locations leads to:

```
[ 0.08 -0.125 0.222 -0.5 2 -3 2 -0.5 0.222 -0.125 0.08 ]
```

But note that the normalization is not correct here, as we're cutting off the infinitely long kernel. Thus, it's better to pick a shorter kernel, such as the [cubic spline kernel](https://doi.org/10.1109%2FTASSP.1981.1163711).

---

A second alternative is to compute the Laplace operator through the Fourier domain. This simply requires multiplying with -π*u*<sup>2</sup>-π*v*<sup>2</sup>, with *u* and *v* the frequencies.

This is some MATLAB code that applies this filter to a unit impulse image, leading to an image of the kernel of size 256x256:

```matlab
[u,v] = meshgrid((-128:127)/256,(-128:127)/256);
Dxx = -4*(pi*u).^2;
Dyy = -4*(pi*v).^2;
L = Dxx + Dyy;
l = fftshift(ifft2(ifftshift(L)));
l = real(l);        % discard insignificant imaginary component (probably not necessary in MATLAB, but Octave leaves these values there)
l(abs(l)<1e-6) = 0; % set near-zero values to zero
```

`l` here is the same as the result above for the ideal interpolator, adding the vertical and horizontal ones together, and normalizing for a length of 256.

---

Finally, I'd like to mention that the Laplace operator is **very** sensitive to noise (high frequencies are enhanced significantly). The methods discussed here are meaningful only for data without nose (presumably synthetic data?). For any real-world data, I **highly** recommend that you use the Laplace of Gaussian. This will give you the **exact** Laplace of the smoothed image. The smoothing is necessary to prevent influence from noise. With little noise, you can use a small Gaussian sigma (e.g. σ=0.8). This will give you much more useful results than any other approach.

Comment: Cris, thanks a lot! This is a really exhaustive explanation! Yes, in my case I have to do with synthetic images and I need to test them with different kinds of pure Laplacians.